# Real function Lebesgue measurable (Homework)

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ a real function Lebesgue measurable over $\mathbb R^{k}$. Show that exists borelians functions $g$ and $h$ such that $g(x) = h(x)$ for $m$-almost everywhere point $x$ and $g(x)\leq f(x)\leq h(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^{k}$.

My answer:
I use the Lusin's Theorem, I supusse that exists $A \subset X$, measurable set, that $\mu(A)< +\infty$ and get a compact set $K$ such that

$$
f|_K
$$ is continuous

Next $f$ is borelian, then we can extend this function to all $\mathbb R^{k}$ with partition unit, remains to get $g$ and $h$.

I think that 
\begin{eqnarray}
g(x) &=& f(x)+1 \;\;\;\; x\in A-K\\
& & f(x) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; x \in K
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
h(x) &=& f(x)-1 \;\;\;\; x\in A-K\\
& & f(x) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; x \in K
\end{eqnarray}

Because $g$ and $h$ are different in a set of measure $0$ because the Lusin's theorem, and then $g=h$ almost everywhere.

It is convincing?